# File association and msconfig broken. Malware?

Tags: windows, malware, file-association, file-types

A friend of mine had an Acer laptop. It has Vista Home Basic. I can't get system properties open. Msconfig does not run. Also, exe filetype is asking me what program to run it with. How can I fix that?

I'm running AVG now.

Assuming nothing shows up, what are fixes to the above mentioned issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reimage. If you're not sure about what viruses are infecting the machine or how it got to that condition, the only sure thing you can do it format and start over or restore from a known good backup.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I don't have an image. A install DVD should work fine though, yes?

Comment: AVG found nothing in safe mode. Now, reinstall Vista or upgrade to XP? Decisions, decisions...

Comment: @Moshe - XP isn't really an upgrade to Vista. I see that you're trying to be sarcastic, but keep in mind that when SP1 for Windows 7 comes out in a few months, Windows XP will be End of Life. Microsoft will still issue patches for it, but software manufacturers will not have to guarantee compatibility with XP to put a Works with Windows logo on it.

Comment: @MarkM - when vista came out and manufacturers where offering xp installs, they called it an upgrade.

Comment: @Moshe - No, they called it a downgrade.

Comment: MarkM - I am fairly certian that Dell Business called it an upgrade, but it makes no difference. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some file association fixes for Vista

http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/105/1/File-association-fixes-for-Windows-Vista.html

Once the exe is fixed, download MBAM and install it, then run it and go to the Update tab and update it twice, then do a full system scan, when it is done scanning, let it remove everything it found as an infection.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

.